making recursive loop more efficient in a number generating function
i have this program where i ask the user to input the weight of plants that were harvested and then how many plants total were harvested, this then generates a list of numbers within a range of +100 or -100 totaling the total weight of the plants that were harvested. my issue is that the recursive function i made will reach the recursion limit a lot and some number pairs just dont work for example, a total plant weight of 123kg with 13 plants total being harvested it just doesnt output the list of numbers.
here is my code
import random
import sys
from js import document, alert

def display_output(text):
    output_div = document.getElementById("output")
    output_div.innerHTML += text + "<br>"

def display_list_item(text):
    list_div = document.getElementById("list")
    new_item = document.createElement("div")
    new_item.textContent = text
    list_div.appendChild(new_item)

def get_inputx(x):
    while True:
       try:
            x = int(input(""))
            return x
       except ValueError:
            display_output("invalid, try again")
                         
def get_inputy(y):
    while True:
        try:
            y = int(input(""))
            return y 
        except ValueError:
            display_output("invalid, try again")
                

def rand_num_gen(z, y, v):
    e = [z + random.randrange(-101,110) for i in range(y)]
    i = sum(e)
    if i == v:
        for num in e:
            display_list_item(str(num))
        display_output(f"These numbers add up to: {i}g")
    else:
        rand_num_gen(z,y,v)
       
def main():
    x = get_inputx(alert(f"enter total weight of plants in kg"))
    y = get_inputy(alert(f"enter total number of plants"))
    v = (x * 1000)  # Total weight in grams
    z = (v / y)  # Average weight per plant
    display_output(f"Your average weight = {z}g"+"-----")
    display_output(f"Total weight = {v}g"+"-----")
    rand_num_gen(z, y, v)
             
sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)
main()

if anyone could give me pointers thatd be awesome
i tried limiting the loops and trying to separate the function into other smaller ones but then it just wouldnt output anything

in your function rand_num_gen you're relying on chance alone to get the correct result. do the reverse: start from the total and then subtract your random numbers minus one, the remnant will look random enough

One obvious improvement would be to eliminate the unnecessary recursion.  This is an iterative algorithm.  Why would you want to consume stack space by making it recursive?

What's the difference between get_inputx() and get_inputy()? Why are they different functions?

Please use meaningful variable names. x, y, z, v provide no context.

The inputx and inputy are different functions because im running the python through pyscript on an html site and when i tried to combine the inputs into one function itd make it so you couldnt make your input on both of them, and idk the letters just seemed easiest to me im too lazy to type out a lot of stuff constantly

I couldnt think of any other way to get the program to do what i wanted without randomly cycling through the numbers. Im pretty new to coding also, but what would you have done instead of a recursive function tom?

@Uzumejia Use a loop.  Wrap the function in an infinite while True: loop, then execute execute a break or return statement where you don't want to repeat the loop (i.e. after calling display_output).

Can you explain the concept of a negative weight? I quote: "a range of +100 or -100". Also, you may have impossible scenarios - e.g, Total weight is 1,000 and 2 plants

I used a negative number in the range because i wanted the list of numbers in e to be within a range of 200 compared to z so lets say the average is 1000 i wanted the lowest number go to 900 and the highest go to 1100 so thats why i used a negative in the range. And yeah there was a lot of impossible cases but i fixed the code
